# Time::Piece is returning a wrong value

Tags: perl

I am trying to convert date from `yymmdd` to `YYYY-MM-DD` with [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) module. With the input as `Nov 31, 2000 (20001131)`, I am getting output as `2000-12-01`. In reality, `Nov 31` doesn't even exists.

```
use Time::Piece;
my $dt_str = Time::Piece->strptime('20001131', '%Y%m%d')->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
print $dt_str;
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `Time::Piece->strptime` would create a GMT date.  Depending upon your timezone, you might an offset in the date.  You'd need to handle that.

Comment: As @devnull says. To clarify, you're not creating a date, you're creating a timestamp with presumably midnight as the time. Then extracting the date-part in your local timezone.

Comment: Why would it be Nov 30?

Comment: With Nov 31 not existing, Dec 1 is IMHO the best approximation (Nov 30 + 1 day). However I'm amazed it doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, it does only rough validation and error reporting, and then performs the same transformations as POSIX::mktime does; any days beyond the end of a month will just cause it to advance the produced date into the next month.  This does seem a little inconsistent; since it allows that for days, I'd also expect it to treat '20005931' as '2004-12-01', but instead it errors out.